# Jenkins is showing "Please wait while jenkins is getting ready to work" continuous, What i need to do?

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I have Jenkins server which has 500+ jobs, suddenly, Jenkins server got rested due to some issue, Now Jenkins still showing "Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work", Please provide the solution for that.

Answer (score 1):

I find that sometimes the browser does not refresh the screen automatically (esp. IE). Wait a bit and hit F5. You should get the login prompt.

Failing that, check the Jenkins logs /logs/jenkins.log for errors. You should find a message  like "jenkins is fully up and running" if OK.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Jenkins running in a Docker container...
I followed the instruction provided by Aftab Ali ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/59559759/13501952 )
I made a fresh install on the Ubuntu my Docker my running on

it works fine since then !

Answer (score -1):

Get fresh installation of Jenkins on ubuntu 16.04 by following the url.

https://www.techbeginner.in/2019/12/how-to-install-jenkins-using-ubuntu-1604.html

Comment: And how would you ensure that action does address the reset problem(and delayed restart) and not introduce more problems?